# MySQL error when sync database using Craft Script from Craft Nitro

Tags: database, mysql, server, multi-environment, nitro

I'm trying to sync the database from staging to local ([Craft Nitro](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-nitro)) using the [craft-script](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts) as per the [article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms).

Here is the error message,

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")" when trying to connect
mysite-db-dump-20210604.sql.gz                                                                   100%   45     6.1KB/s   00:00    
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
*** Backed up local database to /tmp/mysitesite-db-backup-20210604.sql.gz
'zip: invalid option -- '
Try `gzip --help' for more information.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
*** Restored local database from /tmp/mysite-db-dump-20210604.sql.gz
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyncDB with Nitro Fail to sync database from local to staging](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37838/syncdb-with-nitro-fail-to-sync-database-from-local-to-staging)

Comment: Is a different issue, this is using Craft Script, not SyncDB plugin.

Comment: Sorry... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fix the issue after numerous of research, for those who are interested, here is the solution,

> Check output of docker ps command and look for running mysql
> containers. If you find one then use mysql command like this: mysql -h
> 127.0.0.1 -P <mysql_port> (you will find port in docker ps output). If you can't find any running mysql container in docker ps output then
> try docker images to find mysql image name and try something like this
> to run it: docker run -d -p 3306:3306 tutum/mysql where "tutum/mysql"
> is image name found in docker images

Another solution from this is where you have to change the **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp
```

Here is the link for reference,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234379/installing-mysql-in-docker-fails-with-error-message-cant-connect-to-local-mysq

If you having access denied, you may try the below solution, where my-mysql-container is your container name (eg. mysql.database.nitro). Please take note that this will remove your database, try to look for other solutions before coming to this.

```
docker pull mysql 
docker stop my-mysql-container 
docker rm my-mysql-container 
docker run --name=my-mysql-container --restart=always -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd -v /my/data/dir:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql
```

Here is the link for reference,
https://forums.docker.com/t/mysql-docker-will-not-come-up-until-we-restart-the-container/105882

I have forgotten the exact step I use to fix this issue, because I still encounter few issues after this, so good luck.